# Hide bundled items in cart Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, bundle

Wordpress 4.2.2, WooCommerce 2.3.7 and Product Bundles 4.9.3.
When I add bundled item into cart, cart count appears with number of bundle plus all bundled items. Also, those bundled items appear in cart. How can I hide them as useless element for appearance?

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree that the bundled items are "useless", but the bundled items have a specific css class, so you could hide them via CSS:

```
tr.cart_item.bundled_table_item {
  display: none;
}
```